# Getting X results from SQL with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

(Sorry for my bad english, I'll try to be the clearest)

I want to select 5 conversations (over an undetermined number, there could be 5 or 300 conversations) of one user in a MySQL table, and for each of those, I want to select all the users who talk in it.

In a wonderfull world, I'd like to do it with one query.

My query looks like (tables are in french, plz don't hurt me) :

```
SELECT mc.mc_id, mc.mc_sujet, mc.mc_statut,
  miu.mi_ustatut as uself_statut, miu.mi_datelecture as uself_datelecture,
  mi.mi_uid, mi.mi_ustatut, mi.mi_datelecture,
  u.u_pseudonyme
FROM msg_individus as miu
  LEFT JOIN msg_conversations as mc ON mc.mc_id = miu.mi_mcid
  LEFT JOIN msg_individus as mi ON mi.mi_mcid = mc.mc_id
  LEFT JOIN u_individus as u ON u.u_id = mi.mi_uid
WHERE miu.mi_uid = :u_id
```

Where `msg_individus` is the table with participants of a conversation,
`msg_conversations` is the table of the conversation (id, subject, status),
`u_individus` is the table with users' informations.

To select only 5 of those conversations, I added something like

```
GROUP BY mc.mc_id,
LIMIT 0,5
```

But of course, only one user per conversation is given is this way.

I also tried to write `GROUP BY mc.mc_id, mi.mi_uid` but this, like no writting a GROUP BY condition, returns 5 iterations like :

```
(Conversation 1 has two users, conversation 2 has one, conversation 3 has four)
Iteration 1 : conversation 1, user 1
Iteration 2 : conversation 1, user 2
Iteration 3 : conversation 2, user 1
Iteration 4 : conversation 3, user 1
Iteration 5 : conversation 3, user 2
```

What I want is to get five CONVERSATIONS with all their datas (whatever the number of users in it, etc)

I guess I'll have to use two queries (after getting the 5 conversations, I'll get the users per conversations), but maybe you guys can light me with your knowledges.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to get five conversations.  I also suggest that you replace the outer joins with inner joins.  I think the table keys should all have matches:

```
SELECT mc.mc_id, mc.mc_sujet, mc.mc_statut,
       miu.mi_ustatut as uself_statut, miu.mi_datelecture as uself_datelecture,
       mi.mi_uid, mi.mi_ustatut, mi.mi_datelecture,
       u.u_pseudonyme
FROM (SELECT miu.*, mc.*
      FROM msg_individus miu JOIN
           msg_conversations mc
           ON mc.mc_id = miu.mi_mcid
      WHERE miu.mi_uid = :u_id
      ORDER BY rand()  -- not necessary, but why not?
      LIMIT 5
     ) ic
     msg_individus  mi
     ON mi.mi_mcid = ic.mc_id JOIN
     u_individus u
     ON u.u_id = ic.mi_uid;
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected ! For my information (and because I'm a noob), why are inner joins better than outter joins ?
Thx anyway !

Comment: @Vae . . . For two reasons.  The first is that you should use the `join` that best matches your intention.  The second is that an inner join gives the optimizer more opportunities for optimizing performance.